# What statistical test is suitable to summarise patient time in hospital with health condition

Tags: r, hypothesis-testing, statistical-significance, inference, descriptive-statistics

I am working on a dataset in which I am trying to summarise **patient time** in hospital by **age** and any **health condition(e.g Cancer, Deprivatin, Depression or  any)**. In my case it's Deprivatin. **Patient time** contains number of days spent by a patient in hospital. **Age** contains the actual age of a patient. **Health condition** contain   score from **1 to 5** (1 is low and 5 is highest). I also made some graphs and correlated the dataset but I can't make a strong statistical decision based on the graphs because the data  is very close.  Below are the graphs generated from the data and first five entries of the dataset. Total number of entries in the dataset is 5000. **With the given dataset and graphs, what would be the best statistical test for such data, from which a user can summarise *patient time* in hospital by *age* and *health condition*, and make a strong conclusion based on the result of statistical test.**  Thanks

[image]
[image]
[image]

Based on the feedback I got from different answers and comments, I applied MLR and got the following results.

```
    Residuals:
    Min      1Q  Median      3Q     Max 
-8.4344 -3.1339 -0.5236  2.5612 22.7393 

Coefficients:
                         Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)
(Intercept)              2.513551   0.199057   12.49  < 2e-15
data$dep                 0.423002   0.058672    7.21 3.09e-14
data$age                 0.044427   0.002494   18.91  < 2e-15
                            
(Intercept)              ***
data$dep                 ***
data$age                 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Residual standard error: 4.221 on 5130 degrees of freedom
Multiple R-squared:  0.07203,   Adjusted R-squared:  0.07166 
F-statistic: 199.1 on 2 and 5130 DF,  p-value: < 2.2e-15
```

Comment: From what I understand, you want to evaluate the factors contributing to the length of stay of patients in Hospital. From the correlation data, apparently there are no strong correlation between your variables (a moderate correlation between age and dependent). So I can suggest a multivariate regression if the assumptions are met. However, there is no guarantee of a strong conclusion.

Comment: @The_old_man Looking at to the correlation plot, what assumption can be made ?

Comment: @The_old_man. I have added the results of MLR in my question. What can be concluded from the results ? thanks

Comment: Why is `days` on the right hand side in the model formula? Isn't the goal to predict hospital stay (in days)?

Comment: @dipetkov. Sorry that was my mistake. Is it fine now ? I paste the new results. Thanks

Comment: Thanks, it makes more sense. In your place I'd still investigate the model more in depth before trying to make conclusions. At the very least some kind of validation that the model fits the data well.

Answer (score 1):

A regression analysis could be useful in this case. You can estimate a multivariate linear regression model.

Patient time in the hospital will be your dependent variable. Age and health condition (deprivation) will be the independent variables. The estimated coefficients will give you some insights into how age and deprivation are affecting patient time. If both your coefficients for age and deprivation are significant, you can say that they have a strong effect on patient time in the hospital.

You must ensure that your model is reliable before interpreting the results. Make sure there is no heteroscedasticity and the error terms are normally distributed. Check for multicollinearity as well, although it doesn't seem like it should be a problem in your case.

Comment: I have added the results of MLR in my question. Can we conclude something from it ? Thanks

Comment: Both variables show a positive relationship with patient time. This means that an increase in deprivation and age increases patient time in hospital. An increase in deprivation by 1 point increases patient time in hospital by 0.423 days (approx. 10 hours) on average. With an increase in the age of the patient by 1 year, patient time increases by 0.044 days (approx. 1 hour) on average. However, you should further check into how the model is performing and how it fits. Adding some more important variables or a different approach might improve your results.

Answer (score 0):

Your model seem to indicate that age and health condition are significantly associated with the number of days in the hospital. While interpretation of the age is easy (the older the patients, the longer they stay in hospital), your other variable needs more investigation.

I suggest you try dummy coding (google it, many available resources) for your health condition variable, and then investigate each condition separately.

However, last but not least, always check for assumptions of the linear model. [Here is a link for you.](http://r-statistics.co/Assumptions-of-Linear-Regression.html)